# Can't open Scratch org via sfdx:org:open or URL

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, timeout

For the last week I was unable to work with scratch orgs on multiple computers, multiple networks and DevHubs. Simply because I am **not able to open** the always successfully created scratch orgs.

No matter the method. Be it:

- `sfdx force:org:open`
- or getting the URL directly from the CLI

When calling `sfdx force:org:open` I always see:

> Opening org 00D1x0000002UvzEAE as user test-efb8al9z8gxh@example.com
> Waiting to resolve the Lightning Experience-enabled custom
> domain...... done ERROR running force:org:open:  The client has timed
> out. 15:56:38.152 sfdx force:org:open  ended with exit code 1

I tried all of the below without any improvement

1. Different Computer
2. Different Network
3. Switch my Macs DNS from Default to Google 8:8:8:8
4. Upgrade CLI to latest
5. Unistall CLI and install Current
6. Use multiple DevHubs

**BUT: when I use a different project everything works like a charm.**

Comment: Have you tried looking at a network trace with (for example) Wireshark? Should yield clues. If it's a DNS issue, you can then try to narrow it down and perform the same operation via a shell command without sfdx.

Comment: What happens if you switch to a different Dev Hub user?

Comment: @identigral I don't know how to do any of this. Even the URL that I get from sfdx commands doesn't open manually.

Comment: @PhilW You mean a second admin user in the same DevHub org? Didn't try that. Why should that help? What I tried was another DevHub org.

Comment: The funny thing is that it seems to be Project dependant. Another SFDX project works like a charm.

Comment: So what is the difference?

Comment: @PhilW the files in the project

Comment: So are the files already pushed to the scratch org by the time you can no longer open the UI?

Comment: @PhilW Yes they are. Do you think I should open the org before I push stuff there?

Comment: Worth a shot just to see, right? I mean, could it be related to the scratch def instead of the metadata? Or even API version?

Comment: Worked. When I open the org previous to pushing source it opens like a charme. When I then push and open it also works. No clue why?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now (20 June 2022), I'm getting the same error.

I don't think it's the same problem as you were getting Robert, but if people are googling for the same error message, then this is a solution they can use...

The CLI team say:

> Seems enhanced domains is being enabled automatically in new sboxes,
> we got a fix for this but in the meantime you can get the url from
> org:display

https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1556#issuecomment-1155268803

The quick version of the workaround (also from that GitHub issue) is:

macOS:

```
open $(sfdx force:org:display -u <sandbox-username> --json | jq -r '.result.instanceUrl')
```

linux:

```
xdg-open $(sfdx force:org:display -u <sandbox-username> --json | jq -r '.result.instanceUrl')
```

Obviously, you need `jq` to do that, but `jq` is great anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

```
sfdx force:user:password:generate --targetusername $youralias
```

make a note of the new password, then

```
sfdx force:user:display -u $youralias
```

In your browser go to the displayed **Login Url** and log in using the generated password and the username.

To then allow logging in through sfdx you should enable custom domain in the org (You may need to go to Setup -> Release updates to complete this step)

Answer (score 2):

With this, I get the url and pasting that manually to the browser opens the org.

```
sfdx force:org:open -r
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of this.. a little bit of that:

open $(sfdx force:org:open -r | rev | cut -d " " -f1 | rev)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what this does?

Comment: Sure. Aiden suggested using the open command and Damecek suggested using sfdx force:org:open -r which returns a message that ends with the org url.
Hence the title.
The piping is simply extracting the url from the returned message:
1. reverse the message so that the url is at the start of the string
2. cut the message using " " delimiter
3. select the first delimited item (the url)
4. the url is backwards so needs to be reversed again

Answer (score 1):

In instances where `sfdx force:org:open -u <org-alias>` is resulting in the process hanging with a:

> Waiting to resolve the Lightning Experience-enabled custom domain

message, I have found that the solution is the use the *new cli commands that start with* **`sf`**, rather than `sfdx`.

So the replacement command to open the org would be:

`sf org open -o <org-alias>`